# Getting an incremental layout id programatically

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a set of textviews like this..

```
TextView d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8.....etc
```

How can I set text in a loop like this by increment the number after d like this

```
for(int i=1;i<=8;++i)
 {
      d+i.setText("foo");

  }
```

Comment: You need array of `TextView`. you can not use operator to generate variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below.

Create `ArrayList<TextView>` and add all `TextView` in list.

Then after you have to do loop with `List` `size`.

and you can update text to `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("d" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(id);
    tv.setText("foo");
  }
```

the method `getIdentifier()` gets the integer id of a `View` by its id "name".
If this code is not inside an activity, you must provide a valid `Context` for the methods `getResources()` and `getPackageName()`, like: 
`context.getResources()` and `context.getPackageName()`.